# GPS application working well in Karbonn Android phone but not in Samsung and Micromax Android phones

Tags: android, gps

I've made an Android application to get latitude and longitude using A-GPS. When I am testing my application on my Karbonn A21 phone, it is working well, but when I am testing it on my Micromax A116 and Samsung Galaxy duos y, my app is not able to find its location. Why?

I am writing code below

```
 package com.example.gpsutility;





   public class GPSActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 Button search,exit;
 TextView location_tv;
 GpsService gps;
 double latitude,longitude;
 ProgressDialog progressBar;
 int progressBarStatus = 0;
 Handler progressBarHandler;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
    search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    location_tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    gps = new GpsService(this);
    search.setOnClickListener(this);
    exit.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==search)

    { gps = new GpsService(this);
        progressBarHandler = new Handler();

         progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
         progressBar.setCancelable(true);
         progressBar.setMessage("getting location...");
         progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
         progressBar.setProgress(0);
         progressBar.setMax(100);

         progressBar.show();




        new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                  progressBarStatus = getLocation();

                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                          }

                  progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                      Log.e("PROGRESSBARSTATUS",progressBarStatus+"" );
                      progressBar.setMessage(latitude+ "and"+ longitude);

                    }
                  });
                }

                if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             Log.e("DISMISS",progressBarStatus+"" );
                            progressBar.dismiss();

                         location_tv.setText(latitude +"/"+longitude);
                        }
                    });


                }
              }
              }).start();




}


}


        private int getLocation()
        {

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            Log.e("LATITUDE",latitude+"" );
            if(latitude > 0 && longitude > 0)
                return 100;
            else
                return 0;

        }

}
```

The GPS class is

```
   package com.example.gpsutility;



   public class GpsService extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
   boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
   boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
   boolean canGetLocation = false;
   Location location;
   double latitude;
   double longitude;
   public static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES=10;
   public static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*60*1;
   protected LocationManager locationManager;


     public GpsService(Context context)
     {
         this.mContext=context;
         getLocation();
     }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public Location getLocation()
    {
        try {
            locationManager =(LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(!isGPSEnabled || !isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                showSettingsAlert();
            }
            else {
                this.canGetLocation=true;
                if(isNetworkEnabled) 
                 {
                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                          MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                          MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                  Log.d("Network", "Network");
                  if (locationManager != null) {
                      location = locationManager
                              .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                      if (location != null) {
                          latitude = location.getLatitude();
                          longitude = location.getLongitude();
                      }
                }
                 }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


     public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude(){
            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
    }
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        public void showSettingsAlert(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS  settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }



        }
```

Comment: Are you using any specific/third party library or only Android SDK package? Can you run other location application on those devices where your code doesn't work as expected? Could it be that it takes much more time on those device to actually get the GPS satellite data?

Comment: I am using android sdk only , In my micromax phone I am getting location if I turn on google map once and then turn it off.

Comment: please put some snippet.